# Accessing histogram values of Image over Feature Collection in Google Earth Engine after using fixedHistogram with reduceRegions?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I have an ee.Image called image and a grid (an ee.FeatureCollection) called gridnew. First, I am getting the histogram of pixel values in the image over each feature in the Feature Collection gridnew.

`var gridHistos = image.reduceRegions({
      collection: gridnew,
      reducer: ee.Reducer.fixedHistogram(first_class, last_class, num_classes), 
      scale: 90
    });`

Future functions are dependent on these histogram values. I attempted to access these values using unwrappedHistos, which is a list of lists (the outer list represents the features while the inner list represents each histogram of that feature).

`var unwrappedHistos = gridHistos.toList(500).map(function(feat){
  feat = ee.Feature(feat);
  var hist = ee.List(ee.Array(feat.get('histogram')).slice(1,1,2).project([0]));
  return hist;
});`

When I run the following code, I expect to get the 0th value of the first feature's histogram.

`print(unwrappedHistos.get(0).get(0));`

However, this returns an error: "unwrappedHistos.get(...).get is not a function". How can I access these inner histogram values?